# Is it possible to validate form input in PHP without JavaScript as it's being typed?

Tags: php

My task is to display error messages for an email input as the user is typing in it even when JS is disabled. Backend has to use PHP.
I understand that this could work with just HTML and PHP upon form submit using form action=backend.php BUT if I want the errors to show up  as the user is typing I don't think I can do it without a JS oninput event?????
Am I not seeing something?

Comment: Ignoring the JavaScript for a moment: exactly what validation do you hope to achieve on an email address while the user is typing?

Comment: Oh just if it's an actual email address format you know with a single @ and a .

Comment: You won't be able to validate it in PHP while you type without JS (since you need to be able to send the value to PHP in the background somehow). You could make the input of type "email" and then set the input as "required": `<input type="email" required name="email" />` . Then you should at least see an when trying to submit the form if the field doesn't contain a valid email address.

Comment: So, if we take an email address like `someverylongnameindeed@g.cn` , the two characters you're looking for both appear in the last five characters. How would you validate that when the user is still typing the name? With JavaScript enabled you could eliminate unwanted punctuation, perhaps, but realistically you might just as well wait until the user hits `submit`

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular you are exactly right of course but I don't make the rules here. I was given this assignment by the almighty Company. Maybe someone from HR wrote the assignment idk -___-

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 itself has a simple validation and it will show the user some errors without submitting the code to the server

```js
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

you can also have manual patterns :

```
<input type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" placeholder="Enter your email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```